# Material UI InputProps endAdornment: Icon doesn't display inside input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, react-props

having a small problem with displaying icon inside a custom input.

My code is:

```
<TutorialsCommentInput
     placeholder="Write your opinion..."
     style={{ padding: "20px" }}
     fullWidth="true"
     InputProps={{
        endAdornment: (
           <InputAdornment position="end">
              <Icon />
           </InputAdornment>
         ),
      }}
     />
```

TutorialCommentInput:

```
export const TutorialsCommentInput = withStyles((theme) => ({
  input: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#262626',
    fontSize: '15px',
    fontWeight: 500,
    padding: '2px 8px 2px',
    height: '42px',
    color: '#B6B6B6',
    fontFamily: [
      'Nunito',
      'sans-serif'
    ]
  }
}))(InputBase)
```

I've followed every step to do so, the Icon works completely fine outside the input, no clue what's wrong.

Comment: You really need to post the definition of TutorialsCommentInput... I can't know what is going on without that.

Comment: does your icon is a component that return a svg?
The issue could be a oversize icon.
[codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-villani-pr9ty?file=/src/inputComp.js)

Comment: @JeffB I've updated my post

Comment: @codeSandBox – antoineso it's an svg, that works perfectly fine outside the input

Comment: ahaha ok... codeSandBox is a link  that's not my pseudo

Comment: omg my brain is fried aahahah my bad

Comment: anyways, tried changing input to regular input, and trying different svg, still doesn't work

Comment: and if you remove <InputAdornment > tags ?

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: @Fillipo put your icon definition here. It's likely because of that.

Comment: it's a regular svg 

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14.978" height="12.838" viewBox="0 0 14.978 12.838"><defs><style>.a{fill:#0396e6;}</style></defs><path class="a" d="M3.007,17.338l14.97-6.419L3.007,4.5,3,9.493l10.7,1.426L3,12.345Z" transform="translate(-3 -4.5)"/></svg>

Comment: import { ReactComponent as CommentSend } from "../../../assets/commentSend.svg";

Comment: Works [fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-hooks-jyks9?file=/src/icon.js) after removing the invalid style

Comment: I fixed it by using `makeStyles` instead of `WithStyle` [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-villani-pr9ty?file=/src/inputComp.js:242-252)

Comment: @antoineso, you're a legend, thank you!